# Capturing a group of strings that has a specific regex

Tags: regex, string

In my case I want to capture a group of strings that contain a specific number of consecutive characters.

I know I can find that by writing something like:

/('characterHere')\1\1\1\1.../ <- as many times as I want the consecutive string to have the character

which works fine, I can find that string of the consecutive characters in my strings.

My question is once I find a string with that consecutive character I am interested in how can I grab the entire string regardless of the rest of its contents?

ex) 
Sample strings:

```
xxxxxxxxyyyxxxx
xxxxxyyyxxxxxx
xyxyxyxyyyxxxx
```

Notice those three strings had three consecutive y's regardless of the rest of the string.

So:

```
 /(y)\1\1/ can find the three y's in a row,
 but I cant grab the entire string (which is what I want).
```

Comment: So to describe it in english you want the entire string that contains three consecutive y's anywhere in the string?  What platform/language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*?y{3})^.*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/2

Comment: this works, can you explain what the positive lookahead does?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want just this:

```
.*y{3}.*
```